# Magento 2 How to add the custom categories attribute field in product form using Pool Modifier?

Tags: magento2, product, admin, product-attribute, uicomponent

I am trying to add the categories and subcategories in a small panel **Exactly** like the one in the  Product Form in the admin panel.
[image: like so]

**I need to add it in Product Form**

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Add Custom Product Attribute using UpgradeData in already existing module. Also, Update setup_version into module.xml**

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Setup**

**UpgradeData.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.2', '<')) {
            $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            /*  Product Page CMS category ids */
            $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'cms_category_ids');
            $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                'cms_category_ids',
                [
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'label' => 'CMS Categories',
                    'input' => 'text',
                    'required' => false,
                    'sort_order' => 91,
                    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    'backend' => 'VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\CMSCategoryIds',
                ]
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend**

**CMSCategoryIds.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend;

class CMSCategoryIds extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\AbstractBackend
{

    public function afterLoad($object)
    {
        $cmsData = explode(",", $object->getCmsCategoryIds() ?? '');
        $object->setData($this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode(), $cmsData);
        return parent::afterLoad($object);
    }
}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc/adminhtml**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <!-- Save Product Form Custom Field Data -->
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Initialization\Helper">
        <plugin name="save_custom_category_in_product"
                type="VendoreName\ModuleName\Plugin\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\InitializationPlugin" sortOrder="10" />
    </type>

    <!--  Add Custom Filed into Product Form -->
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool" type="Magento\Ui\DataProvider\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="newFields" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">VendoreName\ModuleName\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomCategoryIds</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier**

**CustomCategoryIds.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Text;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Input;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\MultiSelect;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Select;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset;

class CustomCategoryIds extends AbstractModifier
{
    private $locator;
    private $showCategoryList;
    private $cacheManager;

    public function __construct(
        \VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\Config\Source\CategoryList $showCategoryList,
        LocatorInterface $locator
    ) {
        $this->showCategoryList = $showCategoryList;
        $this->locator = $locator;
    }

    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
        /* Add CMS Category Field */
        if (isset($meta['product-details']['children']['container_cms_category_ids']['children']['cms_category_ids'])) {
            $meta['product-details']['children']['container_cms_category_ids']['children']['cms_category_ids']['arguments']['data']['config']['component'] = "Magento_Catalog/js/components/new-category";
            $meta['product-details']['children']['container_cms_category_ids']['children']['cms_category_ids']['arguments']['data']['config']['elementTmpl'] = "ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select";
            $meta['product-details']['children']['container_cms_category_ids']['children']['cms_category_ids']['arguments']['data']['config']['levelsVisibility'] = 1;
            $meta['product-details']['children']['container_cms_category_ids']['children']['cms_category_ids']['arguments']['data']['config']['disableLabel'] = 1;
            $meta['product-details']['children']['container_cms_category_ids']['children']['cms_category_ids']['arguments']['data']['config']['chipsEnabled'] = 1;
            $meta['product-details']['children']['container_cms_category_ids']['children']['cms_category_ids']['arguments']['data']['config']['options'] = $this->getCMSCategories();
            $meta['product-details']['children']['container_cms_category_ids']['children']['cms_category_ids']['arguments']['data']['config']['filterOptions'] = 1;
        }
        return $meta;
    }

    public function getCMSCategories()
    {
        return $this->showCategoryList->toOptionArray();
    }

    public function modifyData(array $data)
    {
        $product = $this->locator->getProduct();
        $productId = (int) $product->getId();
        $cmsCategoryIds = '';
        if ($product->getCmsCategoryIds()) {
            $cmsCategoryIds = $product->getCmsCategoryIds();
        }

        $data = array_replace_recursive(
            $data, [
                $productId => [
                    'product' => [
                        'cms_category_ids' => $cmsCategoryIds,
                    ],
                ],
            ]);
        return $data;
    }
}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Model/Config/Source**

**CategoryList.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\Config\Source;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory as CategoryCollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class CategoryList implements OptionSourceInterface
{
    const COMPONENT_CATEGORY_ID = '2';

    protected $categoryCollectionFactory;
    protected $request;
    protected $parentCategoriesTree;
    protected $storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        CategoryCollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        RequestInterface $request
    ) {
        $this->categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return $this->getCategoriesTree();
    }

    protected function getCategoriesTree()
    {
        $getParentCateroyId = $this->getCategoryId();
        if (!$getParentCateroyId) {
            $this->parentCategoriesTree = [];
            return $this->parentCategoriesTree;
        }
        if ($this->parentCategoriesTree === null) {
            $storeId = $this->request->getParam('store');
            /* @var $matchingNamesCollection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection */
            $matchingNamesCollection = $this->categoryCollectionFactory->create();

            $matchingNamesCollection->addAttributeToSelect('path')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', ['neq' => $getParentCateroyId])
                ->setStoreId($storeId);

            $shownCategoriesIds = [];

            /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category */
            foreach ($matchingNamesCollection as $category) {
                foreach (explode('/', $category->getPath()) as $parentId) {
                    $shownCategoriesIds[$parentId] = 1;
                }
            }

            /* @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection */
            $collection = $this->categoryCollectionFactory->create();

            $collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', ['in' => array_keys($shownCategoriesIds)])
                ->addAttributeToSelect(['name', 'is_active', 'parent_id'])
                ->setStoreId($storeId);

            $categoryById = [
                $getParentCateroyId => [
                    'value' => $getParentCateroyId,
                ],
            ];

            foreach ($collection as $category) {
                foreach ([$category->getId(), $category->getParentId()] as $categoryId) {
                    if (!isset($categoryById[$categoryId])) {
                        $categoryById[$categoryId] = ['value' => $categoryId];
                    }
                }

                $categoryById[$category->getId()]['is_active'] = $category->getIsActive();
                $categoryById[$category->getId()]['label'] = $category->getName();
                $categoryById[$category->getParentId()]['optgroup'][] = &$categoryById[$category->getId()];
            }

            $this->parentCategoriesTree = $categoryById[$getParentCateroyId]['optgroup'];
        }

        return $this->parentCategoriesTree;
    }

    public function getCategoryId($storeId = null)
    {
        return self::COMPONENT_CATEGORY_ID;
    }
}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Plugin/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product**

**InitializationPlugin.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Plugin\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product;

use Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Initialization\Helper;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class InitializationPlugin
{
    /**
     * @var RequestInterface
     */
    protected $request;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     */
    public function __construct(
        RequestInterface $request
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function afterInitialize(Helper $subject, $result, Product $product)
    {
        $productData = $this->request->getPost('product', []);
        if (isset($productData['cms_category_ids'])) {
            $result->setCmsCategoryIds(implode(',', $productData['cms_category_ids'] ?? []));
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

> **After creating and updating the above files run the below command:**

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

php bin/magento cache:clean
```